# Animation not happening until view is change

Tags: android

I have created a rotate animation when the answer is false it shake the CardView,
But it doesn't work until i change the view state such as < cardView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE) >
or calling nextQuestion().
AND Please suggest which class to choose for animation ObjectAnimator, Animation etc..

```
 public void checkAnswer(boolean isTrue) {
        if (isTrue == questionList.get(questionCount).getAnswer()) {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.correct_answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, R.string.wrong_answer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            shakeAnimation();
        }
    }

    public void nextQuestion() {
        if (questionCount < questionList.size()) {
            question_textView.setText(questionList.get(++questionCount).getQuestion());
            question_counter.setText((questionCount + 1) + "/" + questionList.size());
        }

    }

    public void shakeAnimation() {
        Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.shake_animation);
        cardView.setAnimation(shake);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only setting the animation.so whenever the view will be drawn or recreated your animation will work.

You have to call the start animation method on the view to show animation.

**For Example in your case code will be**

```
public void shakeAnimation() {
    Animation shake = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.shake_animation);
    cardView.startAnimation(shake);
}
```

**Difference between setAnimation and startAnimation method**

**- SetAnimation**

when the view is added to the view group, the animation will be called. when the view has been added, the animation will not be called

**- StartAnimation**

the animation will be called all the time even though the view has been added.

**Note:** StartAnimation internally call setAnimation method.